# remote shell command execution error when contains regular expression

Tags: regex, shell, remote-access

The shell command:

```
ssh -t -t eo@fc-ihr-eu-15006.server.com "hostname ; ls /apollo/env/MarkdownService/var/input/beforeLaunch/averageModelAsin\(2014-05-11\|2014-05-18\).txt"
echo "$?"
```

The output log:

```
tcgetattr: Invalid argument
tcgetattr: Invalid argument
Connection to fc-ihr-eu-15006.server.com closed.
fc-ihr-eu-15006.dub8.amazon.com
ls: /apollo/env/MarkdownService/var/input/beforeLaunch/averageModelAsin(2014-05-11|2014-05-18).txt: No such file or directory
2
```

Actually the file exit code should be 0 because the files are matched successfully. There are two questions:
(1) Seems the "ls /path/" is executed on local host but not remote host
(2) Can regular expression be applied on remote host?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might test that you can actually run the command interactively before blaming ssh. This wouldn't have worked without ssh in play either.

Comment: `ls /apollo/env/MarkdownService/var/input/beforeLaunch/averageModelAsin(2014-05-12|2014-05-18).txt` worked, and what I test is after Escape character

Comment: in what shell? Parenthesis don't establish branching patterns in POSIX sh, bash, or others I'm familiar with. If you're using something like fish locally and expecting the remote system to do so as well, well, then...

Comment: `/bin/zsh` @CharlesDuffy thank you, Charles.

Comment: And there's your answer -- your remote system isn't using zsh as its default shell, but you're using a zsh-only pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Neither `ls` nor the remote shell accepts regular expressions. Your command is doing exactly what it should, and is returning the appropriate value. Did you mean to use brace expansion instead?

```
ls /apollo/env/MarkdownService/var/input/beforeLaunch/averageModelAsin{2014-05-11,2014-05-18}.txt
```

Comment: `ls /apollo/env/MarkdownService/var/input/beforeLaunch/averageModelAsin{2014-05-11,2014-05-18}.txt` is different from `ls /apollo/env/MarkdownService/var/input/beforeLaunch/averageModelAsin(2014-05-12|2014-05-18).txt`, first one is "AND", the next one is "OR", the output followed your comments,`/apollo/env/MarkdownService/var/input/beforeLaunch/averageModelAsin2014-05-12.txt: No such file or directory
/apollo/env/MarkdownService/var/input/beforeLaunch/averageModelAsin2014-05-11.txt
Connection to fc-ihr-eu-15006.dub8.amazon.com closed.
2`, however excepted exit code should be "0"

Comment: @jjs, `(foo|bar)` is **not** an OR pattern in POSIX-compatible shells. (It's a pattern in regular expressions, but shell patterns are not regexes).

Comment: Yeah, I can understand your meaning, however, you could find the `OR` logic from the command exit code. For example, `(true|false)` you can get exit code `0` which means successful,and get exit code `2` from `{true,false}` which means failed. Thank you all.

Comment: @jjs, pardon? `{true,false}` runs `true false` (which is what it becomes after expansion), which exits with status 0, since `true` always has exit status 0 no matter what its arguments are. Similarly, `{false,true}` exits with status 1, since `false` exits with status 1 no matter what arguments it's given.

Comment: @jjs, ...and `(true|false)` exits with status 1 in POSIX shells because `false` is the last thing in the pipeline; it is **not** a logical OR, which would be written as `true || false`, not `true | false`.